# What computer specs/ hardware will speed up my Adobe Acrobat OCR speed?

Tags: adobe-acrobat, hardware-rec, ocr

So, I have a work task where I am Sanitizing the PDF, then watermarking it, OCR-ing  it, and password protecting it.

Especially the OCR seems to just take forever, and I'm doing this task on potentially thousands of documents so I'm looking into upgrading my PC to better handle the task.

My question is what component of my PC is most correlated to Adobe Acrobat's performance? Would it be RAM, CPU, or something else?

Currently running with a Intel i5-4690k. 8GB RAM and a Samsung 960 EVO SSD.

Comment: Can you batch process these? Setting up a batch process is likely to result in FAR better performance increases, simply because it won't be waiting for you to set up the next step.

Answer (score 1):

https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2309059 ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190505050822/https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2309059)):

> Acrobat uses only one processor, so it may benefit from the fastest single core. [...] You should use Task Manager to see what limit is actually being reached.

Comment: There are not a lot of processors with better single-threaded performance than an `i5-4690k`.  Yes, the processor is a few years old but pretty darn fast.  You left an important part of the quote out, "Or not.", and it was from another Acrobat user not Adobe.

Comment: @Ramhound "Or not" is redundant with "may".

Comment: I don't disagree.  Except it was said, and was an important part of that quote.